# Как хранить вопросы на установление соответствия в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных

Необходимо создать базу данных, в которой хранить задания. Одни из таких заданий - вопросы на установление соответствия между чем-либо. Подскажите, как организовать хранение таких данных в базе?
[image: Вопрос на установление соответствия]

Answer (score 0):

Думаю можно хранить в таблице вида

```
 Field     Type   Null 
 ID        int     NO   
 P_ID      int     YES
....
```

И для всех под-вопросов заполнять `P_ID` равным `ID` - основного вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Создать 2 таблицы со связкой "один ко многим" - в одной таблице будут храниться вопросы, в другой ответы с привязкой к вопросу по идентификатору в таблице вопросов

Comment: Думаю вопрос был связан с тем как быть если в одно вопросе должно быть несколько ответов( или несколько под вопросов)